# Sum monthly into yearly in SAS

Tags: sql, sum, sas, aggregate

I have the following data set:

```
  Date        Occupation      Count
Jan2006        Nurse            15
Jan2006        Lawyer           2
Jan2006        Mechanic         3
Feb2006        Economist        2
Feb2006        Lawyer           1
Feb2006        Nurse            5
```

The data continues all the way until Dec 2014 with difference occupations and and counts for each occupation. What I want to do is to create an aggregate the counts by occupation all into one year. So assuming that the above data has all the months and counts I want my final data set to look like this:

```
Date     Occupation    Sum
2006      Nurse         20
2006      Lawyer        3
2006      Mechanic      3
2006      Economist     2
and so on until Dec2014.
```

I tried using the first.variable and last.variable as follows but it didn't work.

```
data want,
   set have;
if first.date and first.Occupation then sum = 0;
sum+Count;
if last.date and last.occupation then output; 
run;
```

But this doesn't give me the desired output. I feel like this could be done easily in SQL, but not being familiar with SQL, I am hesitant to use it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using SAS, you can take advantage of the fact that procedures such as `proc summary` group by the formatted value of a variable.  Therefore if you apply a `year.` format to the Date variable, then it will automatically group by year.

```
data have;
input Date :monyy7. Occupation $20. Count;
format date monyy7.;
datalines;
Jan2006        Nurse            15
Jan2006        Lawyer           2
Jan2006        Mechanic         3
Feb2006        Economist        2
Feb2006        Lawyer           1
Feb2006        Nurse            5
;
run;

proc summary data=have nway;
class date occupation / order=freq; /* sort by descending sum */
format date year.; /* apply year format to date for grouping purposes */
var count;
output out=want (drop=_:) sum=;
run;
```

Comment: Although the SQl code below worked too, I had to write another data step to get rid of the duplicates. But this took care of it all. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select year(date) as date, occupation,sum(count) as sum from have
    group by year(date),occupation;
quit;
```

Comment: This works, but there is a slight problem. 
What it does is it creates a Sum column but repeats it 12 times instead of once. 

       Date        Occupation      Count
      2006             Nurse            20
      2006             Lawyer           3
      2006             Mechanic       3
      2006             Economist      2
      2006             Lawyer           3
      2006             Nurse             20
so as you can see, it writes the sum of each occupation for each time it's mentioned, whereas I only want the sum of the occupation mentioned once per year.

Answer (score 0):

In pure datasteps and proc steps method you can do it like below,

```
data test;
  infile datalines;
  input MonYr monyy7. Occupation $ Count;
  datalines;
Jan2006        Nurse            15
Jan2006        Lawyer           2
Jan2006        Mechanic         3
Feb2006        Economist        2
Feb2006        Lawyer           1
Feb2006        Nurse            5
;
run;

proc sort data=test;
  by Occupation MonYr Count;
run;

data result(drop=MonYr Count);
  set test;
  by Occupation MonYr Count;
  retain Sum 0;
  if first.Occupation then Sum=Count;
  else Sum=Sum+Count;

  if last.Occupation;    
  Date=Year(MonYr);
run;
```

You can first change the YearMonth value to Year and perform the sort or just follow my code above.

Comment: Have you tried running this? Coz I just ran it as is without any problem. and produced the same result you asked for!

Comment: Can you tell me what is the error in log or output other than "This doesn't work"

Answer (score 0):

```
    select substring([date],charindex('2',[date]),len([date])),Occupation,sum([count]) 
    from sas group by substring([date],charindex('2',[date]),len([date])),Occupation
```